# how to open a dialog (setting component state) with vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to better control the page state with vue router. For example

- `/` will go to the home page.
- `/login` will stay on the home page but open a dialog with the login box.
- `/register` will open the same dialog but show a registration screen.

How would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, setting a component state from the router would be considered an anti-pattern. What you are looking for is [meta fields](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html).

You should let the component load but in `created()` hook or by observing the `$route` object injected in each component, read the meta config and then update the component's state like:

```
const HomeComponent = Vue.component('home-comp', {

    // Other options...

    watch: {

        $route() {
            if (this.$route.meta.isLogin === true) {
                // Load Login Dialog Box
            } else if (this.$route.meta.isRegistration === true) {
                // Load User Registration Dialog Box
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Your router config would look like:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: HomeComponent,
            // a meta field
            meta: { isLogin: true },
            children: []
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            component: HomeComponent,
            // a meta field
            meta: { isRegistration: true }
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            component: HomeComponent
        }
    ]
});
```

Alternately, you can go away the need for `meta` field. You can simply check the `$route` config for route name or check current URL and then make the decision.

> TLDR; Handle this logic inside your `HomeComponent`. Or use `Guard` if you can use different component for each route.

Answer (score 2):

you can create optional param in home page route

```
routes: [
  {
    path:'/:path?',
    name:'/home',
    component: Home
  }
```

and on Home Component (Or your main component) in mounted or created hook you can look for that param

```
created () {
  if (this.$route.params.path == 'login') {
    // dialog v-model to true
  }
}
```

if created has some issue with your implementation of dialog, mounted should work for you