# vue back button should close dialog if open

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have a vue.js project. The vue-component can create a dialog. If the user presses the back button I want to close this dialog (if it is open) instead of leaving the vue-component. How can I achieve this?

I tried this:

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    let self = this;
    //dialog is open
    if(self.isShowingDialog){
        //closes the dialog
        self.isShowingDialog = false;
    }
    else {
        //navigates back to previous component
        next();
    }
},
```

It works, but not if I open the the component for the first time and the history is empty. In this case the back button exit my app instead of closing the dialog.

Comment: Maybe you can hack this by adding a hash (#opened) to the url when you open the dialog? So when you hit "back", you have something in the history

Comment: I want to cancel the back-navigation if possible. Because if it navigates back every input in the component is lost/cleared. Is it possible to cancel the back navigation?

Comment: Try what @Kapcash said or open your dialog via router and then you will have something in history also, look here how to open via router https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949966/how-to-open-a-dialog-setting-component-state-with-vue-router

Comment: @patonjo I want to cancel the back-navigation if possible. Because if it navigates back every input in the component is lost/cleared. Is it possible to cancel the back navigation?

Comment: unfortunately it is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now with the hashtag/anchor as suggested by @Kapcash. If I press now the back button the dialog is hidden and my main component doesn't close.

MyComponent.vue:

```
<StockChooser v-if="showStockChooser" v-model="showStockChooser">

import StockChooser from "./components/StockChooser";
Vue.component('StockChooser', StockChooser)

data() {
  return {
    showStockChooser: false,
  }
},
methods: {
 openDialog: {
   this.showStockChooser = true;
   this.$router.push('#dialogStockChooser')
 }
}
```

StockChooser.vue:

```
<v-dialog v-model="show" v-if="show" persistent fullscreen>
  <v-row>
    <v-btn color="red" @click="cancel()" style="width:100%">Cancel</v-btn>
  </v-row>
</v-dialog>

data() {
  return {
    show: false,
  }
},
watch: {
    "$route.hash": {
        handler: function(dialog_id) {
            if(dialog_id === '#dialogStockChooser'){
                this.show = true;
            }
            else {
                this.show = false;
            }
        }, immediate: true
    },
},
methods: {
   cancel(){
     this.$router.push(-1)
   },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    history.pushState(null, null, document.URL)
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
        history.pushState(null, null, document.URL)
        // close dialog code
    })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining how it relates to the question.